# Convert string(Date(1646764200000+0530)) to date in the format(dd-mm-yyyy) using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, date, format

I'm Trying to convert the below string to date in the format(dd-mm-yyyy)

```
let dob = /Date(1646764200000+0530)/
```

The above value of Date is given in string,
How to convert it to date using JavaScript,
Tried a lot of methods, but it shows an error as invalid date.?

Comment: what is the format of your string date?

Comment: is `1646764200000` all to be converted? Can you show the expected output from this string?

Comment: `/Date(1646764200000+0530)/` is not a string, it's a RegExp ... did you mean `let dob = "/Date(1646764200000+0530)/"`

Comment: `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(new Date(+(dob.replace(/^\/Date\((\d+)\+\d+\)\/$/, '$1')))).replaceAll('/', '-')`

Comment: @Bravo Yes! I mean "/Date()/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to the DD-MM-YYYY requires formatting.

Here is one way to extract the date portion using the `slice()` method then formatting the output to your desired format. This assumes that the input date is always in the same form and length.

```js
let dob = /Date(1646764200000+0530)/;

let date = new Date(+(""+dob).slice(6,19)).toLocaleString('en-GB',{year:"numeric",day:"2-digit",month:"2-digit"}).split("/").join("-");

console.log(date)
```